# CMake: use default value if not provided on second run

Tags: cmake

When I run for the first run: cmake ..\test2 -DABC=abc
I've got output: ABC=abc
And it is OK, but when I run for the 2nd time: cmake ..\test2 without additional parameter, I still have ABC=abc. I didn't remove any output files.
Is it possible to force cmake to use default value (OFF) of argument if it was provided during next run?

```
if(ABC)
    message(STATUS "abc is set")
else()
    message(STATUS "abc is not set")
endif()
```

doesn't work

CMakeList.txt:

```
option(ABC "test" )
message(STATUS "ABC=${ABC}")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to force CMake to use default value (OFF) of argument?

Yes, just **unset** the cache variable, which can be done with `-U` option:

```
cmake ..\test2 -UABC
```

So `option()` finds the variable to be not set and assigns default value to it

---

In CMake, not using `-D` means "do not change the variable", not a "do not set the variable at all".

Comment: Thx. I didn't know about -U.
Is there option just to unset variable without passing any arguments? I am asking, because I am pretty sure that my teammates and me will forget about -U :)

Comment: "Is there option just to unset variable without passing any arguments?" - If you want to unset **all cache variables**, then just remove `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory or clean this directory. If you want to unset a **specific cache variable**, then you obviously need to specify which variable is needed to be unset.